# Android webview drm content playback

Tags: android, android-tv

I am trying to play some drm content in a webview on android TV, according to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=526058 I need to `grant` RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID so in a class inheriting `WebChromeClient` I have:

```
class CustomWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient() {
    // https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=526058
    override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
        super.onPermissionRequest(request)

        Handler().post({
            request?.grant(arrayOf(RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID))
        })
    }
}
```

When I run this I get an error `grant or deny was already requested`.

I don't see the permission in the app details nor was I asked to grant this permission to the app why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was as simple as not calling `super`.

It turns out that super will by default deny all requests.